# Golang Gorm dynamically create user with map string interface not working

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am building a map[string]interface{} dynamically to create users from an imported CSV file. The map looks alright when I print it, but when I want to create it (add to my database) with Gorm I get an error.

```
for i := range results {

    userMap := map[string]interface{}{}

    for c := range choices {
        if choices[c] != "Unspecified" {
            userMap[choices[c]] = results[i][c]
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", userMap)

    err = db.Model(&models.User{}).Create(userMap).Error
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

The error I receive is:

> zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"

I also activated the Gorm debugger and that outputs:

> ←[33m[2022-01-28 12:05:04]←[0m  ←[36;1m[22.72ms]←[0m  INSERT INTO ""
> DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING "".* ←[36;31m[0 rows affected or returned
> ]←[0m

I checked the official documentation and it states that a create should be possible when using a map[string]interface{}.

I am clueless on why it is not working. Hope someone can help me out.

P.S. The outcome of the printf is:

> map[CreatedAt:1/28/2022 8:25 Email:name@privder.nl FirstName:John
> LastName:Doe
> Password:$2a$23$nZWRc/UD9swTuoeF7XC2mdOrIEMCJzr3H1qrkaNQiE0AUcJrhWmCC]

My User model:

```
package models

import (
    "time"
)

type User struct {
    Id         int        `gorm:"AUTO_INCREMENT"`
    CompanyId  int        `gorm:""`
    FirstName  string     `gorm:"size:24"`
    LastName   string     `gorm:"size:24"`
    Email      string     `gorm:"size:64"`
    Password   string     `gorm:"size:128"`
    Activation Activation `gorm:"size:64"`
    CreatedAt  time.Time  `gorm:"DEFAULT:current_timestamp"`
    UpdatedAt  time.Time  `gorm:"DEFAULT:null"`
    DeletedAt  time.Time  `gorm:"DEFAULT:null"`
}
```

If I would do this, it works perfectly fine:

```
err = db.Model(&models.User{}).Create(&models.User{
    FirstName:  "123",
    LastName:   "456",
    Email:      "789@nl.nl",
    Password:   "sdfsdfnsdfsjdkfh",
}).Error
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

But when I do this, it doesnt work:

```
err = db.Model(&models.User{}).Create(map[string]interface{}{
    "FirstName": "AAAAAA",
    "LastName": "AAAAAA",
    "Email": "aaa@bbbb.com",
    "Password": "sdfsdfnsdfsjdkfh",
}).Error
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

That results in the error:

> INSERT INTO "" DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING "".*

I am using the latest (as far as I know) version of Gorm too. In my go.mod file it states:

> github.com/jinzhu/gorm v1.9.16

Comment: What's the output of `fmt.Printf("%+v\n", userMap)`?

Comment: Are you able to create a record using an instance of the `User` struct? Can you show the definition of the `User` struct? And there's no need to copy the code into the comment. Adding the code to the question is enough.

Comment: Yeah, if i just use models.User{} then it works fine. It just wont work when using a map. Ill update my code with the model.

Comment: `github.com/jinzhu/gorm` doesn't look like the latest version. Go to the bottom of the project's github page, you'll see a link to version 2 repo. You should be importing `gorm.io/gorm` or perhaps `github.com/go-gorm/gorm`, but not the `jinzhu` version, that one's old.

Comment: The version you're using has no support for create-with-map. Compare the [old docs](https://v1.gorm.io/docs/create.html) to the [new docs](https://gorm.io/docs/create.html).

Comment: Oh FML what a brain fart... I will look into updating Gorm. Thanks so much for your help!